# Como obter uma região especifica de um iframe?

Tags: html5, iframe

Criei um iframe a partir de um site qualquer. Gostaria de definir uma região especifica. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com região especifica?

Comment: esta falando de algo que esta contido dentro do iframe ou esta falando de pegar algum valor de atributo?

Comment: Por exemplo, digamos que eu queira pegar um rodapé ou uma div específica. Não é um crawler de dados, mas uma região em pixel (talvez) de um outro site.

Comment: Vc quer exibir no iframe apenas uma parte do site. Mas o tamanho do iframe é dinâmico tb ou fixo?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer ter acesso ao html do site carregado pelo iframe, tem várias formas de fazer, uma delas seria um seletor estilizado para acessar o corpo do site a partir do iframe carregado.

```js
var iframeBody = $('body', $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document); // Acesso ao body do site jsfiddle
console.log(iframeBody.find('ul').width()); // pega a largura do menu do site jsfiddle
console.log(iframeBody.find('ul').height()); // pega a altura do menu do site jsfiddle
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" src="https://jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
```

Veja funcionado no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/q5neL8fg/1/)

Depois que você já tem acesso ao objeto  basta você utilizar as funções .width/height para pegar a largura e altura e realizar outras customizações conforme necessário.

Comment: Não seria acessar o html carregado pelo iframe. Mas, delimitar o conteúdo do iframe em uma região especifica. Por exemplo o site A tem uma região de notícias. Quero criar um iframe no site B com a região específica do site A.

Comment: @BrunoNascimento e só fazer uma cópia do html e colocar este html no iframe

Comment: É de um site dinâmico que preciso de uma área específica. Não posso simplesmente copiar o html.

Comment: @BrunoNascimento pega Dinamicamente!  da uma olhada nesse exemplo, você faz o load da página e carrega só o que você quer, neste exemplo apenas dois links: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/q5neL8fg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja isso o que você quer:

```
window.frames['iframe01'].document.body.innerHTML
```

Ou tente isso para o Firefox ou Chrome:

```
window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML
```

Voce também pode:

Utilizar uma `div` e usar JQuery para carregar apenas a parte que você deseja:

```
$('#target-div').load('http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolio.php #portfolio-sports');
```