# É possível pegar o conteúdo de uma url de um site especifico e exibir em um Popup?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Pesquisei aqui no site e não achei nada sobre isso.

Seria possivel fazer isso ou já existe algo do tipo?

Gostaria de que ao entrar no meu site buscar em um outro site uma imagem ou link e abrir no meu site em forma de PopUp.

Exemplo:  Em uma área especifica do Site "B" tem uma imagem, teria como ao entra no site "A" o popup do site "A" buscasse no site "B" essa imagem e exibisse para o visitante em forma de Popup? estou usando como exemplo uma imagem, mas pode ser qualquer elemento.

Comment: Da pra fazer sim, tem como voce fazer um load da pagina x e  percorrer os elementos dela ate encontrar o que voce precisa, voce pode tanto abrir em algum modal normal e carregar esta pagina quanto pode criar um iframe tambem, se voce colocar um exemplo de site a carregando conteudo do site b eu posso ate criar algo para demonstrar, aqui tem uma resposta que ja te da uma noção de por onde comecar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121047/como-obter-uma-regi%C3%A3o-especifica-de-um-iframe/121057#121057

Comment: Valeu por responder gabriel,  eu criei 2 sites simples para teste. O site B tem 1 imagem  http://sitebteste.blogspot.com.br/  e  o site A não tem nada http://siteateste.blogspot.com.br/ .  se puder me mostra como faria para que a imagem do site B apareça no site A em forma de popup. veja que não quero que apareça o site mas apenas a imagem

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que uma imagem, sim, é possível, desde que seu site saiba a URL dessa imagem. Mas o conteúdo de um elemento, não. Isso tornaria a navegação extremamente insegura. Já imaginou, se o site B fosse por exemplo uma rede social, quando você acessar o site A, ele poderia requisitar informações do site B, e pegar todos os seus dados, contatos e outras coisas privadas.

> Em computação, a política de mesma origem é um conceito importante no
>   modelo de segurança de aplicações web. Esta política permite que
>   scripts sejam executados em páginas que se originam do mesmo site -
>   uma combinação de esquema, nome de hospedeiro e número de porta - para
>   acessar o DOM um do outro sem restrições específicas, mas impede
>   acesso a DOM em sites diferentes.[1] Esta política também se aplica a
>   XMLHttpRequests a menos que o servidor forneça um cabeçalho
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS). Notavelmente WebSockets não estão
>   sujeitos a política de mesma origem.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem